# Pattern matching from a Record type

Tags: coq

I have a record type, for example:

```
 Record matrixInt : Type := mkMatrixInt {
    const : vector nat dim;
    args : vector (matrix dim dim) argCnt
  }.
```

I have a pattern matching where it returns the type of `matrixInt`, I called it `p` for example: (where `function_name p` will return a type of `matrixInt`. I want to separate `p` into 2 fields: `const` and `args`, for example the draft code I want:

```
Definition my_function cons arg p :=
match function_name p with 
 | const => const + cons
 | args => args + arg
end.
```

Could you please help me to write the pattern matching for `p` that returns 2 fields `const; args` ?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For the record (pun intended):

```
Record test :=
{ T : Type
; t : T
}.

(* The fields names are indeed accessor functions *)
Definition foo (x : test) : T x := t x.

(* you can destruct a record by matching against its data constructor *)
Definition bar (x : test) : T x :=
  match x as _x return T _x with
  | Build_test T' t' => t'
  end.

(* You can even destruct a record with a let *)
Definition baz (x : test) : T x :=
  let (T', t') as _x return T _x := x in t'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I have found the answer:`(const p)` and `(args p)`